# Looking for a GIF editor

Tags: graphic-design, image-format, gif

I've been buying [Corel PaintShop](https://www.paintshoppro.com) to edit GIFs because it can do two things:

1. Count the number of colours in a GIF
2. Reduce the size of the colour palette

So, for example, lets say I count the number of colours in a GIF and find out the image only contains eight colours. I can then decrease the colour depth from 256 to 8, which reduces the size of the file.

Is there a free program that can do this?

Comment: Heck, maybe online optimizers might be able to do this for you. Can't say for sure, but you might get more bang for your buck if you convert the gif to a video, but that depends on what you are using it for. This is the reason why giphy, twitter, etc. convert your gif to a `.mp4` video, it compresses the files better. Long story short, delta packets. Anywho, online optimizers for the win I guess.

Comment: My first option was GIMP, you can use it colour tools to do the same and I believe you can pick how colours are stored as well. I haven't really tried gifs that much with gimp

Comment: The image doesn't contain animation. I would like to keep the format as GIF.

Comment: Yes, when you save the file as a .gif file it will prompt you to save as an animation. CLick on the checkbox and you good to go

Comment: Threw me off as well

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because tool suggestions are off topic and this belongs in Graphic Design SE

Comment: I vote to close this question because software recommendation topics belong to [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is a UX question, but I guess I can try answering it.

I just tried GIMP and it seemed to do a good job of dropping the file size. Which is what I'm guessing you are ultimately trying to achieve.

I was able to drop an animation from 506KB to 285KB. If that sounds good to you.

https://www.gimp.org/